# how to add two children to a parent in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have to make a php web application in which each user can add 2 another users. I will get marks and if one if this users add 3 other users then the orginal user who added him will get +1 mark.. so as you see here I need to keep tracking of each added user and by who is added I know there is a tree based sql queries but it will not do the trick because then if a added b and c I can only know that b is added by a and c is added by a but what I really want here is that a has addes b and c so it is like b abd c is in one set that added by a and if the user added another pair of usersc let us say d and e then this pair they will be added in other set that added by a so what is the best way here to that?

more simpler explaining:
let us aay the user a has added the users b, c, d, and e then I need to divide these added users into 2 groups each one conatain only 2 users so I will be able to query the user a in any way you suggest and the resault that I will get is that: the user a have addea two pairs b and c in group 1 that is full and d and e users in group 2 which is full so I will be able to calculate the marks that user a since for each 2 uers that any user add the user that added them will get 5 marke and since user a added 2 groups each of them contains 2 user then I add 10 marks for the user a marks but although if the user b added users f, g, h, q then the user b will get 10 marks but the user a will get only 5 because each user will get 5 marks for each non-direct users that added by him ( they are direct by users that he added) e.g f is non-direct added by a but  he is direct addes by b

Comment: I tried to clean up the question, but I just can not workout what is being said. (-1)

Comment: Please do not add comments to clarify your answer. Please **edit the question, to make it clear**.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, try to breaak it up. At a glance add to your user table a int column called 'references' and set it to 0 on row creation, increment for each user accounted from that user and use a function to work out those above a value of 2.